# Keras - min and max in predicting Y

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How can i set min and max values so the model only predicts Y output between them?

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(units=100, input_shape=(3, ), activation='tanh'),
    Dense(units=18, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(units=1, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(units=1, activation='softmax')          
])


opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0001, momentum=0.9999, nesterov=False)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mae', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])


model.fit(df, target, epochs=300, shuffle=False, verbose=1, callbacks=[estop, rlronp], validation_split=0.2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`tf.clip_by_value`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value):

```
tf.clip_by_value(
    t, clip_value_min, clip_value_max, name=None
)
```

In your code:

```
Dense(units=1, activation=lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(x, -5, 5))
```

Comment: Hi! can you explain why (x, -5, 5) the -5, 5 are giving me better predictions than if i were putting actual numbers that Y is oscilating between?

Comment: Maybe something like the exploding gradient problem? Good question

Comment: for now its predicting stock openings with 0.00210 loss.